# What type of electrical supply is this? (Canada)

Tags: electrical, wiring, subpanel

I'm interested in buying a home-energy monitoring product, the type with current sensors that clamp onto one or more main electrical feed wires.  In order to determine what products would work, and how many sensors are needed, I'm wondering what sort of electrical supply arrangement I have.  It looks to me like there are two hot lines, one neutral, and one ground line.

Specifically, I'm wondering if based on this arrangement, **is all of the current flowing through the neutral line** (i.e. I'd need only one current sensor), or would it fit into another category as shown in the chart below?

Here's an image of the panel (I believe it is a subpanel, it is in a condo building):
[image]

Here are the sort of categories mentioned in the product literature:
[image]

Comment: Chart kinda sucks. "Typical residential service in US and Canada" is 120/240 (split) single phase on 3 wires, and that's what you appear to have, barring an actual measurement or some other indication that you have a 3 phase supply. The first two lines are not in touch with reality, IME.

Comment: It’s also a little odd that the list doesn’t specify 1 sensor needed on line 1, and 2 sensors on line 2, for completeness and clarity.

Comment: That's fair enough - it seems to be the North American version of the manual, from a UK company (not sure if that explains anything)

Comment: Do you have an electric range or dryer you can unplug? If so, can you measure the voltages at its receptacle?  Also, can you post a link to the product you're looking at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You'll need two CTs

The relevant thing is you have a 2-phase panel.

Look at how the fingers on the buses reach out to the bus stab locations.  It's obvious they are alternating A-B-A-B-A-B, and not A-B-C-A-B-C.  That's the bog-standard North American 2-phase design, commonly used for 2-*pole* 120/240V (the second line) or 2-out-of-3-*phase* 120/208V as found in New York City or city apartment buildings (the third line).

2 phases = 2 CTs.  End of discussion.

It really doesn't matter which one you have, as far as the Sense monitor is concerned.

However you will need to tell the Sense whether you have 208V or 240V, because it needs it to calculate KWH correctly.

There's no need to monitor neutral since it can be calculated from the other two and knowledge of 208 vs 240V... assuming nothing is broken.

### The chart is wrong

The first line describes plain 120V service, which is 2 wires from the service.  It is NOT standard North American service - it's extremely rare (though I happen to have it).  You definitely use one CT.

The second line describes normal common North American service.  2 CTs.

### Beware dangerous, unlisted power monitors

While there are excellent power monitor products like Sense that are fully UL-Listed for their purpose... we have also seen some "hobby-tier" power monitors knocked together by amateurs working in their garage, that take very alarming design shortcuts.  UL is telling them "Oh hell no"... but they have been using tricks to slink around the safety standards.  Like get *component* approval from a third party testing lab, then selling the components direct mail *as pieces* to sidestep the system certification.  So the typical installation is a hatchet job, with CT cords and wall-wart cord running in and out of a service panel, *Ethernet* (God save you!) running in/out of the panel, etc.

They market toward "smart geek" types who think the products are oh, so clever.... if they can't even follow the UL White Book like everyone else, how clever can they be?

Comment: Note that while 120/208 2-out-of-3-phase service can be metered using 2 CTs, you *do* need 2 potential elements (read: neutral) to meter 120/208 correctly due to the fact that the two phases aren't quite symmetrical (being only 120deg apart) -- this is why "5 jaw" meter sockets are used for such work (Form 12S/25S instead of Form 2S metering)

Answer (score 0):

This is, unfortunately typical, poor design of the instructions page. Hopefully the product is engineered better than the instructions.

I believe the instructions are *supposed* to show "2 CT Sensors" for **the first 3 rows of the table**. Instead, they only show that for the 3rd row and the table is structured so that it can be instead interpreted as "for the first 2 lines *we have no idea how many CT sensors you will actually need*, and for the 3rd line, 2 CT Sensors". Which of course makes no sense whatsoever. That is basically a "formatting problem" - a disconnect between the engineer's scrawl and the desktop publishing person's implementation.

Except that actually, as I think about it a little more, line 2 - 240V 3-wire is **not** correct. If it were a true "240V only" then it would be 2-wire and 240V. If it were 120V/240V then it would be 3-wire and 120V. Instead it is listed as 3-wire (implying a neutral wire, and therefore 2 wires with CT Sensors, each 120V) and 240V (implying no neutral wire, and therefore only need 1 wire with CT Sensor, 240V). **It doesn't add up.**

As noted by others, the first item *really* should be "120/240". If it was pure 120 (which is possible for very small service) then it would only be 2 wire rather than 3 wire and only 1 CT Sensor - so it does not match the first line, implying that first line, described as "TYPICAL", really should be "120/240".

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on the table - the consensus seems to be that it's poorly done, but this info all helps me understand what will work.

Answer (score 0):

Canadian condo units are fed with 2 phases and neutral. The voltages are 120 volts hot to neutral. 208 volts hot to hot.
This comes from a 3 phase 4 wire service distribution panel found in an electrical closet located on or near the floor that your unit is on.
You WILL need 2 CT's.
The specific unit is the 3rd on the list.

Answer (score -3):

You have the third category: 120/208 volt 3-wire. You have two hots which are out of phase and a neutral. The current through the neutral will vary between 0 and full load depending on how balanced the load is on the hots (0 if the loads are balanced to full if the load is fully on one hot).

[Actually, its a little more complex as you have two phases of a three phase supply so the hots are 120 degrees out of phase, as opposed to a 240 volt system, as in most US residences, where the hots are 180 desgrees out of phase. However, this is close enough.]

You need two current sensors.

Comment: There’s no evidence that this is 120/208 from 3-phase service vs. 120/240 split-phase. Same end result though - 2 sensors needed.

Comment: @nobody I'm assuming that Canadian electrical is all 3-phase since 120/240 volt is not listed as an option. The fact that the OP is in a condo means that it would probably be 3-phase, even in the US.

Comment: The list of options is from the monitor’s instructions. Given that it calls “120V 3-wire service” typical for the US and Canada (patently false) it’s not to be taken too seriously.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I understand better now - regardless of the phase relationship between the hot lines, the total power can be calculated by monitoring those two lines.